# Updating state in parent component when there is state in a child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have code akin the the following in a React Native application:

```
export default function App() {
   const [elementNumber, setElementNumber] = useState(1)
   const arrayElement = myArray[elementNumber];

   ...
        <View>
          {objects.map((wc, index) =>
            MyChildComponent(wc, index)
          )}
        </View>
   ...
}
```

`MyChildComponent` itself has its own state maintained by `useState` hooks. This encapsulates the state and the logic together with the associated visual components, and works.

When the state in the `App` component is updated, the expectation is that the information displayed in the View will be refreshed with new `MyChildComponent` elements.

However, the following error is being thrown:
***Uncaught Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement in React Hooks.***
Digging deeper, the React documentation states

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.
> Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function

Indeed, testing further, the error does not occur if the value and update function in `MyChildComponent` are moved out of `useState`. But while the `useState` in `App.js` can then be updated, the application simply does not work, as the child component is not re-rendered when the data moved out of its state changes.

In the example above, because of the dynamic nature of the data, and complexity of `MyChildComponent`, it would be very difficult to move the useState in `MyChildComponent` to the `App.js` parent. Even if it was possible, the code would be difficult to understand and maintain.

I did try moving the `useState` from `MyChildComponent` to the `map()` function in `App.js`, and then passing both the value and the update function as props to the child component. However, while the application still worked, the issue was not solved, and the same ***Rendered fewer hooks than expected*** error was raised when the state in `App.js` was updated.

What is the correct solution to this in React?

Thanks

Comment: const arrayElement = useMemo(() => getArrayElement(elementNumber), [elementNumber]);
And check if you have the key for your child compoment to identity every ones.
<MyChildComponent(obj) key={object.id} /> // whatever unique value for the key

Comment: How looks like your getArrayElement()? Is it just function which return array?

Comment: How do I add the key? MyChildComponent is not enclosed in <> tags - rather called as a function which returns jsx. I corrected question to illustrate this. If I try to enclose it in tags, get error "Component cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'Element[]' is not a valid JSX element". Thanks

Comment: Also, if the issue is that there is no key, would react not give a more specific error?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to refactor `MyChildComponent` so that it uses props, not arguments. Then, to refactor the calling code like this:

```
    <View>
      {objects.map((wc, index) =>
        <MyChildComponent wc={wc} index={index} />
      )}
    </View>
```

It works even without defining a key.

Thanks everyone very much for their help !